# Aptana/Eclipse: How do I make a project that uses existing files on my filesystem, instead of copying?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I want to create a project that uses source files already on my filesystem, but the IDE always wants to create a directory and make a second copy of all the source.

This has always annoyed me about Aptana and Eclipse, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This is not the behaviour I see in Eclipse 3.5.1 when I select New->Project and choose "Create project from existing source." The project will be created where the source is, adding .classpath, .project, src & bin directories etc. Is that how you're creating the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. have the files in a directory under your workspace
2. use "create project" and change the default folder to the one created above.

Comment: This isn't as good because it forces the project to be in the workspace. Parik's response allows the files to be based anywhere on the filesystem.

Answer (score 99):

I am using Aptana Studio 3 on my mac and the way I do it is:

1. Click on **File**
2. Select **Import** from the dropdown menu
3. Select the **General** tab and open it, you will see the option **Existing Folder as New Project**
4. Select it and click on **Next**
5. On the next page select the folder where you have the old project files, name the new project(if you want to change it). You can also select the languages that you have used on the project.
6. Click **Finish** and you are set to go.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. It's the most direct -- and actually the true intended -- way to do what the question asks, and was the solution I personally chose.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. This works for Ubuntu (and its flavors) too.

Comment: I tried that and it creates an empty project for me.

Comment: This works for me. I´m using Aptana Studio 3 on Windows.

Comment: @Parik Tiwari, Can you please help me to connect to remote server in Aptana Studio 3? It's always giving 'Establishing FTP Connection Failed: Connection Refused' error when I enter Host (localhost), Username (ftpuser), Password(password) details in 'New FTP Connection' under web project. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

One small addendum, the existing folder doesn't actually need to be in your workspace.  I have several projects in my workspace but also several located elsewhere for assorted reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I too wasn't aware of how to do this..

But i tried this way and it worked..

Step 1: Try to create new workspace with the name and location as you wish

Step 2: click new->Java Project

Step3: In the create a Java Project Window select the option for Creating from existing Resource" and select the resource you want

Step4: You can see the project name as automatically set by itself based on the folder containing the project that you select.

Step5: click finish

Step 6: I guess, you need to open Navigator view(Window->show view-> navigator) for best viewing

Hope this works gud.. Post here if its not working,..

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox named "Prompt for workspace on startup". It's in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces. If you check this, on next Aptana startup you will be prompted to define a new Default workspace directory which would be your default projects folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to do that.

1. Create an empty project *(right-click in the Project Window and go to "New->Project" and then "General->Project" and click "Next", after that type in a project name and click "Finish")*.
2. Add a new connection to this project *(right-click on "Connections" and then "Add New Connection")*. The "Source" should be your project and the "Destination" should be the type "Filesystem" with a folder of your choice.

Finished.

I only use that method in very rare cases, as example, if u need a simple file-reference of any folder on your harddrive or if you need an overall file-reference to your workspace folder which contains all project folders, etc..

Answer (score 0):

This answer by no means solves the issue above in Aptana but if you are in a rush, try using FreeCommander http://www.freecommander.com. It is a dual pane file manager with a slew of options.  I have been using it for almost 3 years and there is never a day I don't use it.

What I did for now, is I allowed Aptana to create a folder in the workspace at the same level as the original folder I would like to use.  Using FreeCommander I then have the original (src) folder in one pane with the new folder (dst) in the other pane.

I then manually copy (F5) or use FreeCommander's built in sync function (Alt + s) so that both folders have the same contents at all times.

Again, not the right answer but a workaround as work needs to be done.  Cheers.